# CSS Alignment (Margins not lining up with top right corner)

Tags: html, css, web

I am having difficulty lining up the borders of my div to the top right corner of the container.

Link: https://joshuagrant.github.io/Test/module2/

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: You will get better answers if you can include a minimal example in the question, rather than linked.

Comment: Misunderstood the main issue ... revised my answer and added a bonus suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You have extra padding on `section` tag try to add

```
section{
      padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: Peter, 

Excellent suggestion, I had not noticed that before. You have a keen eye for detail, thanks a lot!

Comment: glad to help you :)

Comment: seems your solution solve another issue, the question (as I understood) is to align the `div`s contains 'chicken,beef,sushi' to the top right corner of the grey containers

Comment: Misunderstood the main issue ... +1 from me (removed my comments and revised my answer)